# after log out form, the main form remains at its place.. any one will help me out for hiding it

Tags: c#

When I login into my application the main form appears but when I log out, the main form remains at its position. I want such that when I log out, the main form should be hidden.

Can anyone help me out?

#### Update:

When I click onto login button, login page appears and when I enter the user id and password it proceeds to main form. When I log out, the main form appears and the controls transfer back to the log in page.  I need to hide that main form when it logs out.  Is it clear now??

Comment: More details are needed before this becomes *answerable*. WinForms, ASP.NET, something else, ... You are talking about logging in and out but you didn't even describe your application.

Comment: the first skill any developer has to learn is how to ask clear, succint questions...

Comment: @Mitch - very well said.
@Abid - if the user has logged out, why would you just hide the main form? Shouldn't it be closed?

Comment: yeah it shuld be closed.. but it remains..

Comment: well, my application comprises of Student Registration Form.. initially i log into it.. and the main form appears.. but when i log out, the main form also appears.. my requirement is that when i click onto log out button, the connection remains but the main form disappears..

Comment: when i click onto login button, login page appears and when i enter the user id and password it proceeds to main form.. but.. when i log out, the main form appears and the controls transfer back to the log in page.. ... i need to hide that main form when it log outs.. ?? is it clear now??

Comment: @Azka: in order to answer your question, we need to know to *where* and *how* these forms are being created and shown. Do you create a new instance of your main form inside the login form? Do you show it with `Show` or `ShowDialog` etc.? If you can post a code sample, it will be fixed in no time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a guess here - you have code in the FormClosing event of your Login form that creates a new instance of your main form and shows it (with Show).